# Robust Large File Transfer with WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I want to transfer big files (1GB) over unreliable transport channels. When connection is interrupted, I don't want  start file transfering from the begining. I can partially store it in a temp table and store last readed position, so when connection is reestablished I can request continue uploading of file from this position. Is there any best-practice for such kind of things. I'm currently use [chunking channel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us a bit more about your scenario...What matters more...CPU or bandwidth? How does transfer time fit in? What is the nature of the links over which this data is transmitted (latency & bandwidth)?
I ask because another option on the table is RDC.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372948%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Eric, this should probably be a comment or at least most of it should - although it does include an answer (-:

Comment: @Eric, I need to transfer very large files over long distances, and the communication channel can be very bad and may sometimes disconnect. And when the disconnection happens, I do not want to start again to upload it, but I would like to start from interrupted position.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: hehe... just install the software from Dropbox.com :o)